# Get The Cameras Current Exposure Duration Value On iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, camera

Does anyone know if theres a property to access the cameras current exposure duration? I want to know what the auto exposure will set the exposure duration at if I set the ISO at its minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`exposureDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624606-exposureduration?language=objc) from [`AVCaptureDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice)

As per apple documentation

> Only exposure duration values between minExposureDuration and
>   maxExposureDuration are supported. The exposure duration can be read
>   at any time